Two finite line segments on a Euclidean 2d plane meeting at a vertex considered intersecting?
This may be a stupid question, but if you have two finite line segments that share an endpoint, would they be considered intersecting? The edges of the line segments do not cross, however they do meet, which depending on the definition could be considered intersecting.
So is there a consensus on if this situation is considered intersecting?

So a point lies on two (both) segments? Then yes.

It depends on the given definitions, which may vary among different textbooks/teachers/languages.
